# Finding the ID of a Salesforce Global Value Set

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm attempting to write an APEX class that will add items to a global valueset, but in order to do so I need to know the ID of the global value set.  Is there a way to find the ID of the global valueset (through APEX, not by looking at the URL) that a picklist field is using? Ideally I'd be able to do something similar to:

```
Case.picklistField__c.getdescribe();
```

and get a response that includes the ID of the global value set that it uses - that way I can then use my the metadataAPI to update the values.

Alternatively if I could find the global valueset by name I could use that with the metadata api as a work around.

**UPDATE**: Was able to get this to work using Eyescreams suggestion with the tooling API - full implementation:

```
    String gvsName = 'TestValueSet'; //name of the global valueset you want the Id for goes here

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset+Where+developername='+gvsName);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http httpreq = new Http();
    HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
    system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, FullName, Description
FROM GlobalValueSet
```

But it's not available in straight Apex queries, you'd need [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_globalvalueset.htm) (meaning a REST callout). You can play with it in Developer Console -> Query Editor, just check the tooling api checkbox on bottom

Comment: eyescream - thanks for your suggestion! I've included an implementation using the tooling api into my apex but now I'm running into an issue... this is a utility class that I need to use in order to test other apex classes.  So I need to call the class containing the tooling api callout from a testmethod but this is causing issues due to the "No api callouts" rule.  

Have you run into this at all?

Answer (score 1):

These days you need to escape the variable like this:

```
String gvsName = 'TestValueSet'; //name of the global valueset you want the Id for goes here

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v48.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset+Where+developername=\''+gvsName+'\'');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```